# Continuation about Getting date between two dates

Tags: c#, sql

My datagridview displays date with the year 2015, even if I set my two datetimepickers from two different dates but with the same year (2016).

Heres my code..

```
public static List<Retailer> GetDataAllRetailer(DateTime past, DateTime present)
        {
        List<Retailer> data = new List<Retailer>();

        MySqlConnection con = DBConnection.ConnectDatabase();
        try
        {   // AND
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tablename + " WHERE (date BETWEEN '" + past.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "' AND '" + present.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "') ", con);

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Retailer rawData = new Retailer();
                    rawData.Date = reader.GetString(1);
                    rawData.Walletid = reader.GetString(0);
                    rawData.Fname = reader.GetString(2);
                    rawData.Lname = reader.GetString(3);
                    rawData.Birthdate = reader.GetString(4);
                    rawData.Address = reader.GetString(5);
                    rawData.Province = reader.GetString(6);
                    rawData.City = reader.GetString(7);
                    rawData.Balance = reader.GetDouble(8);
                    rawData.Frozen = reader.GetDouble(9);
                    rawData.Sponsor_id = reader.GetString(10);
                    rawData.Share = reader.GetDecimal(11);
                    rawData.Email = reader.GetString(12);
                    rawData.Password = reader.GetString(13);
                    rawData.Type = reader.GetInt32(14);
                    data.Add(rawData);


                }
            }



            reader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        return data;
    }

}
```

[image: datagrid]

Comment: Did you check whether the datetime values are correctly transferred to the method?

Comment: If you store numbers and dates as string they wont act like numbers and dates

Comment: yes sir.. this has the same method if i click retailer, sub dealer and dealer radio buttons and its working fine. But when I choose the All radio button it will include the year 2015

Comment: @Plutonix thanks sir but my teacher had given me a database  with date that is varchar..what am i gonna do??

Comment: If you must to work with dates as string, use "yyyy-MM-dd" format so they will evaluate correctly.  Rather than a List<T> a Datatable would do all that transferring for you.  But also use SQL Parameters rather than concatenating strings for SQL.

Comment: Not for nothing but you should take the [Tour] and learn how SO works.  Accepting answers moves them off the Unanswered list and upvoting posts which are helpful helps other users find good answers.

Comment: Make Retailer a class with appropriate properties (DateTime for date, int or double for balance, etc) and just use ConvertToInt(reader["blah"]). When saving, use parameters and SQL will convert back to strings for you. You can convert a reader field into anything it will fit in (numbers to int, dates to date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table column is varchar, then I suggest you to convert it to date to do the search appropriately as follows:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 
 CONVERT(DATE, FromDate) >= CONVERT(DATE, '2016-09-03')
 AND CONVERT(DATE, ToDate) <= CONVERT(DATE, '2016-09-13')
```